# How to Access google sheets offline with python

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-sheets, crud

Actually I'm doing a attendance management system which gets the users Id, in time and uploads it to google sheet. Now the catch is inorder to write in google sheet we need internet, I know I can use Microsoft excel instead, But for certain reason I need to use Google sheets (because it includes a google script). Now I need to know whether I can write to google sheets without the internet or not!!

Comment: Probably start [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6388102?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Comment: Try using the [Sheets REST API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api)

Comment: Hi there @sharandeepak! I strongly recommend you to try the [docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6388102) linked by @BigBen and write back sharing your findings. I don't understand how this question relates to Apps Script, could you please clarify it for me it?

Comment: @Jacques-Guzel Heron currently I'm working on a cross platform project in which users can mark attendance with the help of python. In mobile app the users can request for leave. In order to connect my flutter and google sheets I need google scripts. My clients are requesting to mark attendance offline so I don't know how to connect python and google sheets offline.

Comment: @BigBen it's ok to edit offline manually but I want to know is it possible to access google sheets offline (Programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want offline access to Sheets using Python. If I understood the situation correctly, you only need to give an eye to this guide about [OAuth 2.0 for Desktop Apps](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app), especially the part about [calling Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#callinganapi). Please, ask me any doubts about this approach.